# Network manager connects two devices to the same wi-fi network

Tags: 14.04, usb, network-manager

I have three different computer configurations with the identical Network Manager problem.  I have a home wi-fi unit named ATTXXX.  Each computer has one internal wi-fi interface and one external USB device.  The internal wi-fi chips differ, but all the USB devices are Alfa AWUS036H.  Two computers run Ubuntu 14.04; one is a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.
The problem occurs upon startup.  The Network Manager establishes connections from both the internal and external devices to ATTXXX.  Of course, nothing good happens until I open the Network Manager and disconnect one of the two devices.
Is there any cure for this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Edit Connections..." in the network icon menu.

Find the wireless network name that you're connecting to, select it, and click the Edit button.

In the Wi-Fi tab, look at Device field, and it'll be blank right now, meaning that any interface can use that wireless network. Use the pop-up arrow at the end of the Device field to select the mac address of the interface that you DO want to use to connect. Other devices won't connect now, unless you create another script with their specific mac address in the Device field.

Comment: Thanks, heynnema, for pointing me in the right direction. When I opened the network 'Edit Connections', I found two networks - 'ATTXXX' and 'ATTXXX 1', probably because the box supports both 2.4 GHz and 5GHz bands.  Each already showed a connection one to each of my devices, listed with their MAC addresses as wlan0 and wlan3.  I tried deleting one, and that was fine except it reappeared after a reboot (sigh!)

Comment: Delete both ATTXXX and ATXXX1. Disconnect from both networks from all adapters. Then connect to the wireless network using the adapter of your choice. Then go and edit the newly created script and set the device to either wlan0 or wlan3.

Comment: If my answer helped solved your problem, please rate/accept it. Thanks.